# Python Comparing Nested Lists

Tags: python, compare, nested-lists

I am very new to Python and programming in general. I have found many useful items on this site, but I have also confused myself in regards to what the best way to accomplish what I need.

Simply put, I have 2 csv files, RemoteLA and Master. Each line item contains Order#, LastName, FirstName, MI, Account#. I have to find the items from RemoteLA that are not in Master file. My main concern is matching/verifying Order# first, then Account#, then name(s). There are instances where I can have two of the same order#'s but different names and Account#'s, which is ok as long as it is listed the same in the Master file. Lastly, if the RemoteLA order number is in the Master file, but the account number is listed incorrectly, I would like to print it in a different output than if the Order# wasn't in the Master file at all. Below are my simplified lists.

```
RemoteLA = [['100', 'JACKSON', 'CHRIS', 'D', '12344'], ['110', 'SMITH', 'JANET', 'L' '1223'], ['120', 'STONE', 'MAX', 'W', '1233']]
Master = [['100', 'JACKSON', 'CHRIS', 'D', '1234'], ['90', 'BARST', 'JOEY', 'D', '1344'], ['80', 'NORDON', 'BEV', 'A', '1122'], ['120', 'STONE', 'MAX', 'W', '1233']]
```

Like I said, I have tried many things using sets, list of tuples, etc. My last 'try' was using a while loop as follows-I was just trying to see if I could get the results I wanted, but it appears I am still doing something wrong.

```
i=0
while i < len(RemoteLA):
    j = 0
    while j < len(Master):
        if RemoteLA[i][0] == Master[j][0]:
            if RemoteLA[i][1] == Master[j][1]:
                if RemoteLA[i][2] == Master[j][2]:
                    print('All match')
                elif RemoteLA[i][2] == '9999':
                    pass
                else:
                    print('Account number does not match')
            else:
                print('Name does not match')
        else:
            print('Order number does not match')
        j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

Any help or push in the right direction would be very much appreciated. Sorry for the wordiness. Thank you.

Comment: your 3 ifs can be replaced by `all(a == b for a,b in zip(RemoteLA[i][, Master[j]))` although that 9999 thing is strange

Comment: in Python you don't do such nasty index variables. Better use **for ll in RemoteLA**, etc. No need to have such C style index variables

Comment: I actually have 4 'Remote' files to compare and in one of them the account number is listed with all 9's--so until this gets fixed, any account numbers listed as 9999 I want to pass without anything being done.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, account numbers are unique.  Therefore use them as dictionary keys.  Here, let's reorganize your data:

```
def orderSummary(lst):
  info = collections.defaultdict(dict)
  for item in lst:
    acct = item[4]
    orderinfo = info[acct]
    ordernum = item[0]
    if ordernum in orderinfo:
      print "duplicate order number"
    else:
      orderinfo[ordernum] = tuple(item[1:4]) #the name
  return info

remote = orderSummary(RemoteLA)
master = orderSummary(Master)
```

Now we are ready to check the remote against the master:

```
def checkRemoteAgainstMater(remote,master):
  for acct,info in remote.items():
    masterinfo = master.get(acct,None)
    if masterinfo is None:
      print "bad account number {}".format(acct)
    else:
      for order in info:
        if order not in masterinfo:
          print "Master missing order"
        elif info[order] != masterinfo[order]:
          print "name mismatch"

checkRemoteAgainstMater(remote,master)
```

hth.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This sounds like it is my best option. I will work on this a bit,

Answer (score 0):

A much shorter (although just as inefficient) would be:

```
import itertools
for master,remote in itertools.product(Master, RemoteLA):
    if all(r == m for r,m in zip(master, remote)):
        print "Match", master
```

A more efficient version would be to sort the lists first (O(nlogn)), in order to have a O(n) comparison.

Comment: That was my bad. My lists are all sorted by order #, but my test lists above were manually entered out of order.